# JSON php parsing error

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Help please, I´m new to JSON and php and I´m getting an error I don´t know why I get.

What´s wrong with my code?

```
    <?php

$host = "(My real info here)";
$user = "(My real info here)";
$password = "(My real info here)";
$db = "(My real info here)";

$sql = "select * from user;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,&sql);

$response = array();

while(&row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    array_push($response,array("name"=>$row[1]),"class">$row[3]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I´m getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Comment: `$` !== `&`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: `array_push($response,array("name"=>$row[1]),"class">$row[3]));` Here's a hint... you're parenthesis don't match

Comment: Thanks Feederkun, horrible mistake by myself

Comment: And thank you very vey much Machavity, I need to start training my eye